# Neo4j Cypher: How to convert mysql table to graph nodes for given sample?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

MySQL Table with Columns Names as (Name, Value):

```
Name Value

A    V100
B    V200
C    V300
A    V101
B    V202
C    V301
```

How do we convert the above table to graph:
Labels should be as follows:

```
Label A
Label B
Label C 
Nodes (a:A{V100}),(a:A{V101}) 
      (b:B{V200}),(b:B{V201}) 
      (c:C{V00}), (c:C{V301})
```

The Problem is that in the table the value A, B, C are generic. In future any other values may be added like D with values V400 & V401 or E with values V500 & V501.

Hence, the cypher query should be generic in order to create the nodes.

Comment: 1. Vanilla Cypher does not support creating dynamic labels, so you'll need the [APOC library](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_creating_data). 2. What is you input? Is it a CSV file? 3. How would you like to store the values? Would a simple `value` property suffice?

Comment: Input will be csv file. Values could be stored as simple property. Can you pls give me an example in APOC ?

Comment: Sure, I added my answer.

Comment: If this answer satisfies your needs, please accept and optionally upvote it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vanilla Cypher does not support creating dynamic labels, so you'll need the [APOC library](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/).

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/some-file.csv" AS line
CALL apoc.create.node([line.Name], {value: line.Value})
YIELD node
RETURN count(node)
```

For a guide on `LOAD CSV`, check out [this blogpost](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/) and also the [Cypher documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/load-csv/)